# VB Script called within a VB Script

Tags: vbscript, wsh, byref

We are calling a VB Script (say Script B) within a VB Script (Script A) using `ByRef`.

1. Script A calls multiple other scripts before calling B and they work.
2. ALL scripts are placed in the same folder.
3. The issue is that B isn't getting called!
4. If we double Click B, it works just fine!

We debugged as follows.

1. We tried to debug by placing `MsgBox` just before/after calling B. And also as the first statement in B. None gets displayed.
2. Just to see if the correct Script Path is being called, we removed B and the Script A hangs - indicating it couldn't find B!

I am not sure what's the issue, it's puzzling and odd!

Appreciate any suggestions as how to go about resolving the issue!

---

***UPDATED***

My Apologies! There are too many lines of code to post the script(s) in their entirety. Hence posted textual descriptions. Here are snippets from the code.

Note

1. `MsgBox` Before the Script B call displays just fine!
2. `MsgBox` Right after Script B call also displays just that "ReturnCode" is blank!
3. `MsgBox` in Script B (the very first line) doesn't get displayed.

**Script A**

```
'...
'...

MsgBox "ready to execute Script B"

If swPrint Then
    cmdExecute = RootDir & "Scripts\Master\Application\" & ScriptB & " //B " & _
    "-JOB=" & strJobNumber & " " & "-APP=" & strApp & strEnv & strMRO & strZIP & " " & "-QAPDF=" & strQAPDF & " " & "-QAPRNT=" & strQAPRNT
    MsgBox "execute Script B " & cmdExecute
    ExecuteStep cmdExecute
    MsgBox "back from Script B " & ReturnCode
End If


Public Sub ExecuteStep(ByRef ExecCommandLine)
    If swStartStop Then
        ReturnCode = VSShell.Run(ExecCommandLine, , True)
        CheckForError ReturnCode, intStep, ExecCommandLine
    End If
End Sub
```

Script B

```
MsgBox "in Script B"
'....
'....
```

Appreciate your time in looking into this. Do let me know if these snippets doesn't make sense. Thank You.

---

Still getting used to the EDITs on the Forum. Appreciate @omegastripes taking time to edit the message.

As far as the output of "MsgBox "execute Script B " & cmdExecute" is concerned, it's nothing but the Path to Script B File with Parameters. These are the same parameters that are passed to all the Scripts prior to Script B.

\\ScriptB -PARAMETER1 -PARAMTER2..

Thank You.

Comment: Can you include the actual code? Textual descriptions are nice, but how do you suppose anyone can point out a programming error without seeing the program?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. It is hard to assist you if you don't provide a [mcve]. And, according to your test 1, if not even the "`MsgBox` before calling B" is displayed, I assume your code doesn't even reach that part so the problem should lie before that. In any case, we can only assist you if you share the problematic code

Comment: Please edit the question and add the output from the line `MsgBox "execute ScriptB " & cmdExecute`.

Comment: You are obviously new...this site is not a forum do not start off with that assumption. I'd recommend you look through the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [ask] before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Point 1.

If you want to send back a `ReturnCode` from `ExecuteStep` you need to make it a function:

```
Function ExecuteStep(ExecCommandLine) 
    If swStartStop Then 
        ReturnCode = VSShell.Run(ExecCommandLine, , True) 
        CheckForError ReturnCode, intStep, ExecCommandLine 
    End If
    ExecuteStep = ReturnCode
End Function
```

Then

```
If swPrint Then
    ...
    ...
    ' This will call ExecuteStep and pass back the ReturnCode
    ' ----------------------------------------------------------
    MsgBox "back from Script B " & ExecuteStep(cmdExecute)
End If
```

Point 2

I suspect Script B is not getting called because `swStartStop` is evaluating as `False`... either in error or because of a typo. It would be better to use `Option Explicit` at the top of your script, this will force you to declare (`dim`) all variables and will pull up typos at run time. Also pass all required variables to the function as arguments to make the flow of data more clear.

```
Function ExecuteStep(ExecCommandLine, swStartStop)
```